# Using curlpp to make GET and POST calls to HTTP server

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, curl

Hey I have quite a bit of programming experience but it has been a while. This is my first program other than assignments in school so I need some help using curlpp to make HTTP calls to a server. I downloaded the c++ curlpp from the google code page extracted the .tar.gz then linked it with the references libraries in visual studio but when I compile I get this error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Crypto, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 10/1/2013 12:19:24 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Crypto.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\jay bell\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\crypto\crypto\curlpp\include\curlpp\cURLpp.hpp(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'curl/curl.h': No such file or directory
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.39
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So I know that Visual Studio is looking in the right place as it is inside the curl header file but what it seems like to me is when it adds the header (cURLpp.hpp) it is trying to reference curl/curl.h which does not exist within the folder curlpp (I have confirmed this by looking for it) Just wondering if someone could help me with this the only thing I have in my code is this

```
#include "curlpp\include\curlpp\cURLpp.hpp"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

}
```

thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: Oh god I know I did but am not sure what the fix was as this was so long ago now and I handed the project off to a programmer who took it and converted it to java! Sorry!.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot open include file: 'curl/curl.h': No such file or directory

To use curlpp, you need to install libcurl.